# Is there a way to create and download a react component on the fly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a case where I need to render a react component on the fly and download the output as an image, I started writing an example to achieve this goal but it seems that the library I'm using is not able to generate the react component. If you look at the downloadFile function in the code below, you will recognize that I'm passing a react component to the function, the file seems to be corrupted,  I changed the image type to be text but it didn't work:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Eye from "./Eye";
var fileDownload = require("js-file-download");

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  downloadFile() {
    fileDownload(<Eye position="left" />, "filename.txt");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.downloadFile}>Click Me!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;





import React, { Component } from "react";

class Eye extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.position}>
        <svg height="100" width="100">
           {" "}
          <circle
            cx="50"
            cy="50"
            r="40"
            stroke="black"
            stroke-width="3"
            fill="red"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Eye;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try using `dom-to-image` module

see this, https://codesandbox.io/s/kx0z37mlo5 this is working example for downloading component as image

hope this will help

Comment: dom-to-image needs an id of html element in the page, you can't pass it a react object as per my understanding.